# angular js inject user data to airbrake

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, airbrake

Currenlty i'm developing app using angular js but still figuring out how to send user's data to airbrake. I'm using ng-token-auth to handle the authorization ([ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth))

**This is my factory**

```
'use strict';

app.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$injector', function ($injector) {
    function log(exception, cause) {
      if (currentEnv === 'dev') {
        Airbrake.push({
           error : {
             message : exception.toString(),
             stack : exception.stack
           },
           params : {
             user : how_to_add_user_here
           }
         });
      }
    }
    return(log);
  }]
);
```

How I can inject the user to the factory?

Really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'use strict';

app.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$injector', 'user', function ($injector, user) {
    function log(exception, cause) {
      if (currentEnv === 'dev') {
        Airbrake.push({
           error : {
             message : exception.toString(),
             stack : exception.stack
           },
           params : {
             user : user.name // for example
           }
         });
      }
    }
    return(log);
  }]
);
```

Comment: That is my old question. it was the most helpful in finding the solution tho so i accepted this. Thanks a million for your answer! :)